# Parse.CurrentUser is not returning new data (Xamarin IOS)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xamarin

I have an IOS app built with Xamarin and Parse.
I'm having problem when I make any change in the user (ParseUser) and try to get the information afterwards like:

```
    ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    IList<ParseObject> sports = parseUser.Get<IList<ParseObject>>("sports");
```

Here, sports is showing null, but it shouldn't, since there is data on column "sports" for this user when the code reaches this line.
It seems to me that CurrentUser is not being updated after I call

```
    await user.SaveAsync();
```

If that's the case, how can I fix this?

Thank you,
Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a bug with Parse. 
I contacted their staff and they will take a look at it. 
While waiting for them to solve I have found a workaround, that is not really elegant, but it is working for me.

Basically, what I'm doing is to call LogInAsync() again, so this way, I force it to bring the latest information from the database.

```
ParseUser parseUser = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(user.Username, user.Password);
```